# Handling Unicode character in Mule's dataweave

Tags: unicode, mule, dataweave

We have a [DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-reference-documentation) expression wherein the payload, for some of the fields, special [unicode control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters) are coming.

This is leading to a WeaveExecutionException with the following message:

> Exception  while executing:
>   "userComment": "CA*2249*0*1763335*54133300896010155
>
> ^ Unexpected character '\u000a' at payload@[8:116] (line:column),
>   expected  '"'.

Below is the payload which we are getting. Here, in the field `usercomment`, a `\u000a` (new line character) is coming:

```
{
    "dcsId":"11840000000000001",
    "accessToken":"jaskjadkjsa",
    "profile": {
        "comments": {
            "feedback": [{
                "feedBackType":
                    "5",
                    "userComment": "CA*2249*0*1763335*54133300896010155
1" }
                        ]
                    }
                },
    "platform": "iphone"
}
```

Below is the logged Exception which we are getting in the console:

```
com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException: Exception 
while executing:                                                                 
"userComment": "CA*2249*0*1763335*54133300896010155

^
Unexpected character '\u000a' at payload@[8:116] (line:column), expected 
'"'.
```

Below is the DataWeave script we are executing:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload
```

Does DataWeave have no support for unicode control characters?

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing transformations using either JSON to XML or XML to JSON please set `Content-Type  'application/json; charset=UTF-8'`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a related question from earlier: [How to get more information about dataweave exception in muleosft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445786/how-to-get-more-information-about-dataweave-exception-in-muleosft)

According to this: you are supposed to escape the special, "control unicode characters".

Instead of new line, you are supposed to have `\n` in your JSON.

Please see also: [How do I handle newlines in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json)

For details see the JSON standard; the [ECMA - 404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf).

In this document on the page 9, in the chapter "String" you can see a detailed description how the unicode control characters should be represented in JSON.

A JSON string must not contain a new-line charachter. Your JSON data has invalid format, what leads to an Exception.

[image: Formal description of the JSON strings from the ECMA - 404]

According to this: You have to make sure that the unicode control characters are properly escaped in your JSON strings.

Answer (score 0):

In datawave use the operation `as :string`

In your case:

```
"userComment": "CA*2249*0*1763335*54133300896010155 as :string
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting invalid whitespace character while converting your JSON to XML, then first we need to find in which it is reflecting; after that, we can use `replace /{unicode value}/ with ""`.

We can use Java code to remove non-printable characters from Unicode.

```
package org.mycompany.utils;

public class whiteSpace {
    public static String myInvalidChar(String text) { 
        /* strips off all non-ASCII characters */
        //text = text.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
        /* erases all the ASCII control characters */ 
        //text = text.replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\r\n\t]]", "");
        /* removes non-printable characters from Unicode */ 
        //text = text.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "");
        //return text.trim();
    }
}
```

Which ever the error that you are getting, you can uncomment and use the code import to dataweave and use the method at the field level.